# Is it unprofessional to ask a coworker at your workplace to review your resume?

Tags: resume, colleagues

I am a co-operative education student at my plant and am interested in working here full-time. However, I do not graduate from college for another year and am still actively searching for other job offers in the hopes of getting something better than where i currently work. I am expecting a job offer here as well, and they know my intentions to come back after graduation if I do not find something better. I want them to review it, since they are likely similar to the people at other companies who will be reviewing my resume for job openings and know what areas to improve or specific words and language to use.

Should I ask others in my department to help review my resume? Or is that unprofessional because it tells them that I am still searching for other jobs? In general is this a bad practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is **perfectly** **okay** to do so. I was an intern once, and, in fact asked a few of my coworkers including boss to help me out. They knew I was a student and it wasn't guaranteed I would get a position there after my internship so they had no issues with me asking for help.

That being said it is always good to get different eyes on a resume, so try to find another source of input. School, family, classmates, etc.

Answer (score 3):

In your very specific situation it would be OK to ask your co-workers for input. Co-operative education is meant to prepare you for the workforce. Although resume preparation is almost certainly not included in the career development opportunities a co-op employer explicitly provides, they should not be surprised or offended to be asked.

That said, consider whether you would ask any of these people to review your resume if they were not your co-worker. Someone you barely know has little motivation to take some time out of their normal responsibilities to help you personally. If you have mentor(s) with whom you've developed rapport, it is certainly OK to ask.

Please note that under normal circumstances it is not professional to ask co-workers to review your resume. Even as an intern, rather than a co-op it would be questionable.

Finally, although it is OK to ask co-workers whom you know fairly well, consider their experience. If they've been in their role for a long time and haven't revised their own resumes then the advice may be dated. There are free  to low-cost resume services available and nearly every college and university offers resume building workshops, consultants, or even seminars. The advise of a professional with the job you seek may tell you what to list on the resume but a professional resume preparer can make that information stand out.

Answer (score 2):

> Should I ask others in my department to help review my resume? Or is
>   that unprofessional because it tells them that I am still searching
>   for other jobs? In general is this a bad practice?

Certainly it's okay.

Generally, internships are as much about learning and putting yourself in the best possible position to launch a great career as they are about doing work. You aren't bound to take a position with them. You may not even be offered a position.

When I hired interns, I often gave them help on improving their resumes. Sometimes I hired them (and didn't need to see their resume), sometimes I helped them find jobs elsewhere and gave them a terrific recommendation.

Some companies will feel offended that you are looking elsewhere, but in my experience most won't.

Answer (score 0):

Does your college have resources for resume preparation?  Usually there a job center for helping with the particular issue.
While I wouldn't deem it 'unprofessional' if a colleague asked me to review their resume, I'd also be fairly indifferent to providing you with serious feedback, particularly if this was detracting from my professional duties.  I guess what I mean to say is best case scenario, you get some marginally helpful input on the formatting of your resume.  Worst case scenario, you annoy a coworker and out yourself as an intern who is seeking employment beyond the company you are working for.  All in all, **it's a better idea to seek for job preparation resources from your school**.

Comment: To be rather blunt, my school has very poor resources. I have asked for help in the past but it was not much use. I mainly want to get advice from someone with experience in the field, but I have no personal friends who are in this field. I have a lot of good "general" feedback. I just want something a lot more specific to me. I have been told I have a good resume, I just want to turn it into a "great" resume.

Comment: Makes sense.  In that case do you have anyone that has been assigned with helping you at your internship?  I'd try to find someone that could be a mentor and had expertise in the industry and ask for their help.